# Write application for analysis of satellite imagery of dates from cvs file

Tags: python, image, csv, satellite

I want to write an application/ software, preferrably using python, which will allow me to read in a csv file which contains dates and will then save satellite imagery from these dates.

Before I attempt this I want to know if this actually possible using an existing web-based api from sources such as NASA?

Sorry for a vague question but I have not been able to find any answers thus far and do not want to begin an impossible task as I am quite new to programming, so any advice on this question is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see! Here is a request for imagery of the O2 Arena on the river in London for an image from January 2017:

```
curl "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery/?lon=0&lat=51.5&date=2017-01-01&cloud_score=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY"
```

Here is the result:

```
{
  "cloud_score": 0.047324414226919846, 
  "date": "2017-01-17T10:52:32", 
  "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC82010242017017LGN00", 
  "resource": {
    "dataset": "LC8_L1T_TOA", 
    "planet": "earth"
  }, 
  "service_version": "v1", 
  "url": "https://earthengine.googleapis.com/api/thumb?thumbid=a286185b3fda28fa900a3ce43b3aad8c&token=206c7f1b6d4f847d0d16646461013150"
```

If you paste the URL at the end into a browser, you get the image.

Here are some others:

- https://earthdata.nasa.gov/earth-observation-data/near-real-time/download-nrt-data
- https://api.nasa.gov/#getting-started
- https://earthdata.nasa.gov/api

Answer (score 0):

Read CSV from Python: yes.
Use Web-based API from Python: yes.
Download images from Python: yes.
Save images from Python: yes.

Does NASA provide an API? Does it support what *you* want to do with it? These are questions you'll have to elaborate more on what you have tried and what NASA's website shows.